# PhoneGap error when using ripple

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I get a weird error when I press ok, it just continues to load but doesn't do anything.

[image]

I have a simple HTML, CSS and JS file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/DevPro/Mobile/phonegap-2.8.0/lib/android/cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\boaz\WebstormProjects\FirstApp\script\script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\boaz\WebstormProjects\FirstApp\style\style.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<!-- header -->
<header>
    <p>hello</p>
</header>
<!-- header -->

<!-- content -->
<section>
    <p>content</p>
</section>
<!-- content -->

<!-- footer-->
<footer>
    <p>footer</p>
</footer>
<!-- footer-->

</body>
</html>
```

I use ripple to emulate.

Why is it like that? And what do I need to do?

Comment: Check the source of phonegap on your pc. `file:///C:/DevPro/Mobile/phonegap-2.8.0/lib/android/cordova.js`

Comment: i dont see any problem with my cordova source

Comment: Ok, it was only an observation.

Comment: Mind posting your solution? (assuming you found one)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `Cordova-2.8.0` js file that you added belongs to Android? In other words, is the `cordova-2.8.0` js file specific to Android? This error usually occurs when you add iOS specific JS file or vice versa in your Android project. If this is not the case, you may want to check the file path. Perhaps, you can copy the Android cordova JS file into your project and link it in your index.html file from there.. That should do.

Comment: No that is not the case i have taken my cordova file from the lib -> android. The only thing wired is that every guide shows the cordova x.x.x .js while i dont have a cordova 2.8.0 js file it is just called "cordovs.js"

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap from 2.7 and above has these annoying alerts.  Does hitting cancel 3 times work?  Another option is do not load cordova.js when in chrome.

See answer here: [Phonegap / Cordova 2.7 Mutes Console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702865/phonegap-cordova-2-7-mutes-console-log)